# If Duplicate Only Return Oldest Entry

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I need a way to return all data - and if there is a duplication in the data return the oldest entry.  I tried to get creative and use the `Row_Number()` function, but when I run the query it only returns all the data where the database has multiple rows.
What I am after is returning all rows, and **IF,** the `StoreNumber` exists multiple times only return the oldest based off of `OpenDate` how should this query be modified so that not just the oldest is returned, but also the rest of the data as well?

```
;With CTE As
(
    Select
    StoreNumber = clsStoreUQ
    ,StoreName = StoreName
    ,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY OpenDate)
    ,MCC = ROUND(CAST(COALESCE(MCC,0) AS INT),0)
    ,SCC = ROUND(CAST(COALESCE(SCC,0) AS INT),0)
    ,OpenDate = RTRIM(LTRIM(OpenDate))
    FROM OPENQUERY(XX.XX.XX.XXX,'Select
                                    iv.clsStoreUQ
                                    ,cm.storeName StoreName
                                    ,iv.jbOpenDate OpenDate
                                    ,SUM(case when wp.SaleCat = 1 THEN CAST(jc.amount AS DOUBLE PRECISION) else 0 end) MCC
                                    ,SUM(case when wp.SaleCat = 3 THEN CAST(jc.amount AS DOUBLE PRECISION) else 0 end) SCC
                                    FROM saleData iv
                                    INNER JOIN StoreData cm
                                    ON cm.storeID = jb.storeID
                                    INNER JOIN saleDataSub jc
                                    ON jc.clsStoreUQ = jb.clsStoreUQ
                                    INNER JOIN saleCategory wp
                                    ON wp.SaleCat = ac.SaleCat
                                    GROUP BY iv.clsStoreUQ, cm.storeName,iv.jbOpenDate')
)
Select
* FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Is OpenDate a date field or a string?  Why are you doing RTRIM/LTRIM on it?

Comment: it is a date field.  I am using TRIM on it due to the fact there is added whitespace at the end of the dates for a few of them, and in order to get them to return in the query, I needed to add TRIM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only the oldest rows you should order them starting with the oldest.

i.e.

```
 RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoreName ORDER BY OpenDate DESC)
```

But it's really strange that "there is added whitespace at the end of the dates",
maybe you store the dates as `strings` and `order by` can have no sense of order in this case.

Comment: ... that would be the NEWEST records.  OP had it right originally, but I do suspect that the "date" field is weird.